# SQL4306N Java stored procedure or user-defined function could not call Java method

Tags: java, db2, java-stored-procedures

We just upgraded to DB2 10.5 from 9.5, this process was working fine until the upgrade was performed on the server. When i run the jar file from a linux server, I get the following error however when i run the exact same code from eclipse on my windows computer, it works just fine! I am also getting a similar error if I calll this sp from DB2 control center. I am looking to know what is causing this and how can i fix this error?

SQL4306N  Java stored procedure or user-defined function "ESADBM.GETNEXTID", 
specific name "WHDBRMM_UTILS" could not call Java method "GetNextID", 
signature "(Ljava/lang/String;[I)V".  SQLSTATE=42724

Explanation:

The Java method given by the EXTERNAL NAME clause of a CREATE PROCEDURE
or CREATE FUNCTION statement could not be found. Its declared argument
list may not match what the database expects, or it may not be a
"public" instance method.

User response:

Ensure that a Java instance method exists with the "public" flag and the
expected argument list for this call.

sqlcode: -4306

sqlstate: 42724.

Here is the code:

```
    package pkgUtil_v4_0_0_0;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException;


    public class DBSequence {
      public static final String SEQ_CONTACTID        = "ContactIDSeq"; 
      public static final String SEQ_PROJECTID        = "ProjectIDSeq";
      public static final String SEQ_LOCATIONID       = "LocationIDSeq";
      public static final String SEQ_SOURCEID         = "SourceIDSeq";
      public static final String SEQ_SURVEYID         = "SurveyIDSeq";
      public static final String SEQ_LOGICALSURVEYID  = "WageAreaIDSeq";
      public static final String SEQ_WAGEDETAILID     = "WageDetailIDSeq";
      public static final String SEQ_ORGID            = "OrgIDSeq";
      public static final String SEQ_OFFICEID         = "RegionNumberSeq";
      public static final String SEQ_LETTERID         = "LetterIDSeq";
      public static final String SEQ_DODGEID          = "DodgeIDSeq";
      public static final String SEQ_CRAFTID          = "CraftIDSeq";
      public static final String SEQ_CRAFTTITLEID     = "CraftTitleIDSeq";
      public static final String SEQ_ANALYSTID        = "AnalystIDSeq";
      public static final String SEQ_LETTERTEMPLATEID = "LetterTemplateIDSeq";
      public static final String SEQ_RECRATESID       = "RecRatesIDSeq";
      public static final String SEQ_BRIDGESCDID      = "BridgeSCDIDSeq";


      public static String drvr = "";
      public static Connection con = null;

      // utility function
      public static int getNextId(Connection lcon, String sequence) throws         SQLException {
        Boolean bFlag;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        int id = 0;

        String sql = "select next value for esadbm." +
             sequence + " from SYSIBM.sysdummy1";
    //    System.out.println("String = "+sequence);
        stmt = lcon.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
          id = resultSet.getInt(1); 
        }
        resultSet.close();
        stmt.close();

        return id;
      }

      // Stored Procedure Entry Point
      public static void getNextId(String sequence, int[] seq) throws SQLException, Exception {
  System.out.println("String = "+sequence);
  System.out.println("Array = "+seq);
        if (drvr.length() == 0) {
          drvr = "jdbc:default:connection";
          con = DriverManager.getConnection(drvr);
        }
        drvr = "";
        seq[0] = getNextId(con, sequence);
        con.close();
      }

      // test procedure 
      public static void main(String args[])throws SQLException, Exception {

        try {
          System.out.println("Connecting to DB " + args[0]);

          Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
          drvr = "jdbc:db2:" + args[0];
    //      System.out.println(drvr+args[1] + args[2]);
          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2:" + args[0], args[1],args[2]);
    //      System.out.println(con);
            System.out.println("DB Connection Successful");
          con = DriverManager.getConnection(drvr, args[1], args[2]);

          Statement st = con.createStatement();
          String query = "set schema = 'ESADBM'";
          st.execute(query);

          System.out.println("Getting ID");

          int id = getNextId(con, SEQ_SOURCEID);

          System.out.println("Returned : " + Integer.toString(id));
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
          cnfe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle) {
          sqle.printStackTrace();
        }    
        catch (JDBCConnectionException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to connect to database");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is the stored procedure:

```
               CREATE PROCEDURE "ESADBM  "."GETNEXTID" 
                                    ( 
                            IN      SEQUENCE   CHARACTER(40),
                            OUT     ID   INTEGER
                            )
                                    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 0 
                                    SPECIFIC WHDBRA_UTILS 
                                    EXTERNAL NAME 'pkgUtil_v4_0_0_0.DBSequence!getNextId()' 
                                    LANGUAGE JAVA     
                                    PARAMETER STYLE JAVA     
                                    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
                                    FENCED THREADSAFE 
                                    MODIFIES SQL DATA 
                                    NO DBINFO;
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "run[ning] the jar file from a linux server", but you need to make sure that the JAR file containing the class used by the external stored procedure is properly installed on the server. So, what steps did you perform to install it? Your Java and SP code are completely irrelevant here.

Comment: we execute the jar file on a linux server. I have not made any modifications to the existing setup on the server since the previous build was working completely fine with DB2 9.5 and only stopped working after upgrading to DB2 10.5. Does this make sense? I've been researching how to resolve this issue and have been unsuccessful thus far. It seems like there could be a mismatch between the parameter types being passed in the method as compared to the stored procedure or something to do with the classpath?

Comment: You may want to read [how to properly install Java external routines](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0006348.html)

Comment: Mustaccio, if you know more about this, is it possible to have a phone call? I am on EST.

Comment: Sure, I charge $90/hour for remote consultations. Where do I send the contract?

Comment: sorry, that was an attempt as sarcasm. Apparently it failed.

Comment: Thanks for making fun of me when I'm in dire need.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries for external routines, including Java classes and JAR files for Java routines, must be present in a certain location in the DB2 instance directory. When you upgrade your DB2 version, a new instance is created, but those libraries are not copied automatically (which, by the way, makes sense as there is a good chance that they need to be rebuilt).

The error message indicates that the instance cannot find the Java class file that implements `GETNEXTID` -- that would be `DBSequence.class`. The class needs to be copied to the `sqllib/function` directory in the DB2 10.5 instance home on the database server, as [explained in the manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0006348.html). You will probably need also to create `pkgUtil_v4_0_0_0` under `sqllib/function` for the correct package structure. Make sure you compile the Java source using the same JDK version as the one used by the DB2 instance to run the program.

Once you do that, execute `CALL SQLJ.REFRESH_CLASSES()` in the DB2 client of your choice to make sure DB2 reloads the most current version. After that your stored procedure should work correctly.

Having said that, I don't really understand why you use such a convoluted way of retrieving a SQL sequence value.

Comment: So, which part of the error message seems unclear? As a Java geek, you probably know that Java identifiers are case-sensitive, don't you.

Comment: Well, it's not working now and the error message tells you why. However, if you see no reasons to believe it, then I can only wish you good luck.

Comment: I'm in the middle of trying it, will keep you posted!

Comment: Great. Do you need more help interpreting error messages? Check the admin notification log for the stack trace, then check the DB2 manual for the meaning of SQLCODE=-204, then fix your code, as a geek you say you are.

Comment: Mustaccio - Thank you lots for your help last week! It turns out the DBA was at first using the wrong case to call the SP and then not using the correct input parameters to call the stored procedure or all this wouldn't have been an issue! I agreed with everything you said and being new at my current company wanted to double check with other people that I am not crazy! Thank you again for your help, I hope I can pay back one day!